# SharpDX: How to read Texture2D with custom color format?

Tags: c#, image, directx, texture2d, sharpdx

Good day!

There are two image files. Two different color format.
B8G8R8 (without alpha) and B4G7R4A1.
I want to read them as Texture2D.
Is it possible?

Thx!

Comment: Have you tried Texture2D.FromFile ?

Comment: FromFile uses ImageLoadInformation.
ImageLoadInformation uses SharpDX.DXGI.Format. =\
B8G8R8 I found in SharpDX.Direct3D9.Format (class Texture, DirectX9). I do not understand why it is not in DX11. I want to work with a single entity. =\

Comment: those formats don't exist anymore in DirectX11, so your best bet is to convert your textures in a dx11 friendly format (B8G8R8A8_Unorm , DXT1/BC1 ) being pretty good candidates.

Comment: I get it. =\ Thank you! ^)